# Understanding Ruby modules behaviour

Tags: ruby, module, scope

So I've just recently started writing some Ruby and whilst I understand how modules work, the following behaviour still throws me off.

```
module ModuleA
    def a_greet
        'Hello from module A'
    end
end


module ModuleB
    def b_greet
        'Hello from module B'
    end
end


include ModuleA
include ModuleB

# WHY DOES THIS WORK !!!!!
p ModuleA.b_greet
```

I get that the functions from the modules can be called without specifying `Module.` and that I'd never write code in this way, but I cannot understand why you can call a method included from ModuleB when explicitly stating ModuleA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wait, there's more:

```
"Why does this work?".b_greet # => "Hello from module B"
```

You're including those modules in a top-level object `main`. It's a special object: all methods defined on it become available to all objects (see the line above, there's now `b_greet` method on a `String`). `ModuleA` is an object too, so, when you include `ModuleB`, `ModuleA` gets its methods. If you include those modules in a regular class/object, you won't get this "sharing" behaviour.